# Devise error after upgrading

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I just upgrade to devise 1.2 and now on production I get the following error:

```
2011-05-27T02:43:26+00:00 app[web.2]: RuntimeError (Devise changed how it stores objects in session. If you are seeing this message, you can fix it by changing one character in your cookie secret or cleaning up your database sessions if you are using a db store.):
2011-05-27T02:43:26+00:00 app[web.2]:   config/routes.rb:158
2011-05-27T02:43:26+00:00 app[web.2]:   lib/rack/www.rb:7:in `call'
```

How do I resolve this? Thansk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fix this error by changing one character in your cookie secret or cleaning up your database sessions if you are using a db store for your sessions.

To change your cookie secret change the secret_token in your rails config file.
For more information on sessions and security in rails see this [link](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html).

If you need any help with this feel free to ask me.

Answer (score 2):

You can resolve it by doing what it says.